# Struggling with $push with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

So I feel like my code is honestly not that complex, so it's driving me absolutely wild trying to figure out why I can't get a simple array with no nesting in my Mongo collection to update! This is what I'm currently working with:

```
console.log("documentID: ", documentId); //string defined elsewhere
console.log("userId ", userId); //string defined elsewhere

const targetUser = await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(
          userId,
          {$push: { documents: documentId }},
          { new: true }
 );

 console.log("targetUser:", targetUser);
```

The output comes out as:

```
documentID:  6077c0d308ba09c77206b81b
userId  6072623145acaf65f7390e11

targetUser: {
    createdAt: 2021-04-15T04:13:45.226Z,
    _id: 6072623145acaf65f7390e11,
    documents: [ '6073db2c6bbd3d64bd694307' ],
}
```

I removed most of the irrelevant and sensitive fields, but basically the problem comes down to this: I'm trying to push a new documentID into the documents array of a specific user saved in my User collection, but when I try, what happens is that the targetUser object is returned completely unchanged (the id in there was already there before). Even running the program multiple times, displays the exact same result, so I know it's not an issue of a lag in what's being logged otherwise I would see the updated array the following times I run it. The fact that it's successfully logging the desired targetUser object tells me that it's neither a database connection issue or an issue with how the _id field/query is formatted. I feel like that only leaves $push as the potential problem, but based on what I've read here and elsewhere, I don't think I'm using it incorrectly?

Some other things I tried:

Using `updateOne({"_id": userId}, [similar args])`. Had the same exact issue.

I also tried using

```
const targetUser = findOne({"_id": userId});
targetUser.documents.push(documentId);
```

This one gave me an error to the tune of "can't find "push" for undefined, and when I logged targetUser.documents I did indeed get undefined, even though logging just targetUser gave me the same expected result as above. I then tried logging the result of `Object.keys(targetUser);` and got some funky results, but I guess according [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209253/14979534), it's because "Mongoose always return an instance mongoose object, which is immutable by default." What I was seeing was pretty much the same as what the OP of that post was seeing.

I also tried importing ObjectId from the mongodb npm package and casting my userId variable to ObjectId before re-trying the updateOne() and findByIdAndUpdate() methods. I tried it with both `ObjectId(userId)` and `new ObjectId(userId)` though that unsurprisingly didn't change anything, since the correct user object containing the specified ID is showing up and isn't really the problem.

I suspect that the documents field is read-only or immutable for some reason, though I don't have a clue why that would be. Would appreciate a helping hand :)

--

Edit: Also tried adding the argument to the findOne() and findByIdAndUpdate() methods to try to log the results and errors, but there isn't an error firing, so it didn't tell me much. I also tried some of the other variations of the "find" functions.

--

Edit: Solved! I didn't include a "documents" key and corresponding array in the schema ‍♀️

Comment: Can you add your mongoose model for the users collection?

Comment: @stefOb Just added it~

Comment: Thanks. I don´t see any "documents" property in your userSchema. Did you miss it?

Comment: @stefOb, that was it ‍♀️ Thanks for the help!