# Querying documents in mongodb, shows additional unnecessary information in the terminal.Please check code and terminal screenshot. I'm using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

async function getCourses()
{

```
return await Course.find({author:'NARESH RAMINI'});
```

}

async function run(){

```
const result=await getCourses();
console.log(result);
```

}

run();

**Below is the Terminal's output for the above code for retrieving documents from mongodb**

[Terminal populates with additional information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zGr8.png)

**What can be done to make the terminal show only or populate only queried documents from mongoDB?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a single field for all documents in a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-for-all-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: @varman The link you've provided has a different question. please check the screenshot attached to my question. Problem is terminal populates with unnecessary  information, which only suppose to show queried documents. There should be a setting to make terminal to show only result of documents.

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209253/7975771

Comment: @varman Yes it solves the issue. Thank you very much!